# Get id from AndroidAlarmManager oneShotAt in a callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I've stuck a bit with a callback function for android alarm manager.
Anyone knows maybe what do I need to do to make it right and get an ID to printHello function (eg 123 - is unique and need to pass it -  because it's necessary for reading data from DB when callback function executes)?

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(
        DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds: 1)),
        123,
        printHello,
        alarmClock: true,
      );

     printHello() {
       // how to get id?
       // need it to read from db 
      final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
      print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
    }
```